# Making a single copy of a singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

a design question:

I have a singleton (in objective-C but it doesn't really matter)

The singleton is a class (object) that is actually a data structure that many classes access, and is single (hence - a singleton)

Now I want to add the ability to undo - which is actually saving a snapshot of the state of the object - so I can go back to it.

What I actually need to do is to break the singleton-ness of the object (need one copy of it).
But this will not allow me to share it conveniently between all the classes.

Ideas?

Comment: You should look into NSUndoManager; it keeps a stack of messages and arguments to restore state, which is much more efficient than copying the entire model.   In my opinion copying is a concept which does not fit nicely into the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1):

**"The singleton is a class (object) that is actually a data structure that many classes access, and is single"**

I think it is easier to make your singleton object have a collection of the data structure. Then you just create copies of the data structure instead of copies of singleton.

Comment: Interesting... a bit of overkill (because it will change all the clients and currently I need only a single undo). But I like the out of the box thinking...

Answer (score 1):

The singleton pattern came in vogue about 10 years ago when design patterns were first being adopted by developers. In the years since then, the singleton has fallen into disuse because it is notoriously difficult to mock in unit tests.  So the simplest answer is to abandon the singleton pattern completely in favor of a more friendly pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a `- (id) copy` method in your singleton class.

In this method, allocate a new instance of your class, and set all it's properties to a copy of your shared instance's properties.

Comment: I was thinking in that direction (seems like I have no choice becuase of deep copy). What's the difference between this and using `NSCopying`?

Comment: wait... My singleton implementation has 
`+(id)alloc {
    @synchronized([MomentCreationShared class])
    {
        NSAssert(_sharedMySingleton == nil, @"Attempted to allocate a second instance of a singleton.");
        _sharedMySingleton = [super alloc]; return _sharedMySingleton;
    }
    return nil;
}` How do I get around this?

Comment: This is not the way apple recommends to make a singleton.
You could do it this way : 

`+ (id)sharedInstance {
    static MySingleton *instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}`